# cygwin support for ucontext.h user context switching

Tags: cygwin

It appears that cygwin doesn't support user context switching (supported by `ucontext.h`).

Given I need to developed a user-context switching application under cygwin, is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably write your own implementation, wrapping around the Fiber API.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682661(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you could try the [Context](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/context/doc/html/index.html) from Boost, it has a similar interface.